# Top bar customization with dconf-editor in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: gnome-shell, dconf, transparency, top-bar

I've made Ubuntu dock transparent with `dconf-editor` by changing `background-opacity` value to 0 in the path `/org/gnome/shell/extensions/dash-to-dock/`. But I don't see a path to edit top bar transparency anywhere. How to edit top bar settings with `dconf-editor?` I've already tried the `dynamic-top-bar` extension, but didn't work, as I can't turn it on. Is top bar bound with the `gnome-shell` or the user theme?

Comment: its not configurable by anything other than user shell theme.. concentrate on "user shell" theme..

Comment: @PRATAP ok I will do so. Thanks for shining the light in the correct path :)

Comment: I think this will work. Thanks. Let me check.